# Converting string of ASCII code list to byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, string-conversion

Hello my database has some string like "24629702857295607830195970123951263875654....". This string is produced as below:

```
fs = new FileStream(samplePicture.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
br = new BinaryReader(fs);
bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
```

Something like that is only converting the numbers to its ASCII character and it is not what I want:

`byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(byteString);`

If it was a hex string it can be converted by having substrings with 2 length parts. But I couldn't  convert this type of string. If you don't want to write the code it works also just an idea how to separate ASCII characters like : 246, 29, 70, 28, 57,...

**Summary Edit: Actually I am trying to reverse the string back to its byte array. String is generated like here:**

```
    fs = new FileStream(samplePicture.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    myStringBuilder.Append(bytes[i]);
```

I can't reach the file or anything else. All I have is this string.

Comment: Given that string, I don't see how you can differentiate between 2 digit and 3 digit codes. "123123" - is that "12, 31, 23"? Or is it "123, 123"? How do you tell?

Comment: You don't need (or want) `BinaryReader` there -- just read the bytes directly from the `FileStream`, or use `File.ReadAllBytes`

Comment: It's not clear to me what your file actually contains. Is that "2462970..." what you see when you open the file in a text editor, or is it what is returned by `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(byteString);`?

Comment: If file is some (ascii) text, why don't read as text one: `string text = File.ReadAllText(samplePicture.Text, Encoding.ASCII);`? If file is binary, `byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(samplePicture.Text);`

Comment: @canton7 it is not my code It is just how the string generated. I don't have anything but this string. And it is generated by the code in the question. Let me add some more explanation sorry

Comment: What is the actual question? How to convert pre-existing strings back into bytes? probably cannot be done. How to store binary data in a string? just use base64. Something else?

Comment: I still don't know what you did in order to see that string. Did you open the file in a text editor, and that string is what you saw? Did you print your `byteString` variable? Where did the `byteString` variable even come from? It isn't asssigned in the code you posted

Comment: @canton7 Ok, I edited the question. Also the same string is recorded to database with type varbinary(MAX) and when you copy the text you can see the "string".

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yes you are right. It can be done like that. but the problem is I don't have the file or file path. Only string.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I don't know :D

Comment: Use UTF8 not ASCII since you have code 246.

Comment: @jdweng yes but this conversions only look for string characters for example it converts 123 to [49] [50] [51] but actually it is "{" character

Comment: ASCII encoding will remove non printable characters.  UTF works the same but does not remove characters like ASCII. UTF-8 will change only a couple of characters like 0x80.  If you are using character > 0x80 do not use ASCII unless you want the character removed.

Comment: Yes thank you for your comment I understand but encoding is not what I look for. Because it is already encoded into bytes which is concated. The problem is converting it to byte array. For example if my string is "123456" it might be converted to byte array like [12], [34], [56] or like [123] [45] [6]. there should be standard or something for this conversion.